# JS / Coffee + HTML, simpler way to set conditional class

Tags: javascript, html, coffeescript

So, when I'm rendering html templates from javascript (or coffeescript, I use both depending on the circumstances), I find I have a really common case that seems unnecessarily clunky. For example:

I have a JS object like this:

```
var thingy = {
  name: 'Some Thing',
  category: 'widget',
  active: true
};
```

I might want to render this into html like so:

```
<div class="widget active">Some Thing</div>
```

The bit that always feels clunky is turning a boolean check in javascript into a css class string. What I normally end up doing is something like this:

```
function renderThing(thing) {
  var klass = thing.active ? thing.category + " active" : thing.category
  return '<div class="'+klass+'">'+thing.name+'</div>';
}
```

In coffeescript this feels longer since the ternary is more verbose:

```
renderThing = (thing) ->
  klass = if thing.active then thing.category + " active" else thing.category
  '<div class="'+klass+'">'+thing.name+'</div>'
```

This isn't too terrible when there's only one such property but if you end up in a situation with three or four the code quickly gets very verbose.

So, I was wondering, does anyone have ideas/suggestions on a more concise and/or readable way to do this?

Comment: `klass = thing.category; if (thing.active) klass += " active"`?

Comment: Could you be more specific about the "*situation with three of four*", maybe an example code? Do you mean four ternary operators? Is looping possible?

Comment: @Bergi yes I mean with multiple ternary operators, for instance if an object can have more than one type of state like `selected` or `current` or `active` or `disabled` or `bookmarked` etc. I've tried not to give an overly-specific example because I'm thinking about this more as a general problem that I find is frequently faced in javascript programming.

Answer (score 2):

If I was doing a lot of these then I'd write a simple function to, more or less, provide my own "cast boolean to string":

```
if_true = (f, s) ->
    return s if(f)
    return ''
```

Then a bit of string interpolation to build the class string:

```
klass = "#{if_true(o.active, 'active')} #{o.category}"
```

If you don't like the stray space when `!o.active` then you could move that space into the `if_true` argument:

```
klass = "#{if_true(o.active, 'active ')}#{o.category}"
```

And if you have a whole bunch of flags, toss their names in an array and use a loop comprehension to build an array of class names:

```
o =
    first: true
    second: true
    third: false
    fourth: undefined
    fifth: 'element'
    category: 'pancakes'

flags = [ 'first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth' ]

klasses = (if_true(o[f], f) for f in flags)
klasses.push(o.category)
klass = klasses.join(' ')
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/eGDaa/

Answer (score 1):

> This isn't too terrible when there's only one such property but if you
>   end up in a situation with three or four the code quickly gets very
>   verbose.

Indeed it will. Looks like a perfect place to use assign from switch -- that is, if there will only be one "add-on" class:

```
score = 76
grade = switch
  when score < 60 then 'F'
  when score < 70 then 'D'
  when score < 80 then 'C'
  when score < 90 then 'B'
  else 'A'
```

But that would be 1 input equals 1 output, which might not be what you want. Maybe you need:

```
renderThing = (thing) ->
  cssClass = thing.category
  keysToCss = ["active", "disabled", "delta", "gamma", "epsilon"]

  for k,v of thing 
   if lodash.contains(keysToCss, k) # I'm using lodash here, same as Underscore
     cssClass += " #{k}" 

  "<div class='#{cssClass}'></div>"
```

Also, I think once you start mixing markup and code like this you need to start investigating a tool like Angular.

Comment: Actually I don't generally mix markup and code, but almost always use javascript templates to keep markup out of the code. The problem is that in the templates themselves I often run into a situation where I want to convert certain attributes of a model into a pattern of class names. Usually I will write a function or something like `model.className()` which performs the logic, but even then the logic ends up feeling very complicated considering this is such a conceptually simple thing.

Answer (score 1):

Check coffeescripts [loop comprehensions](http://coffeescript.org/#loops) to iterate a bunch of flags and build a list which you can concatenate to the class value:

```
renderThing = (thing) ->
  flags = ["selected", "current", "active", "disabled", "bookmarked"];
  klasses = (f for f in flags when thing[f])
  klasses.push thing.category
  "<div class=\"#{klasses.join(" ")}\">#{thing.name}</div>"
```